# Why does the height on html element not have effect?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 70vw;
      height: 40vh;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    h1 {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code above I set the `width` to `70vw` and the `height` to `40vh`.

I have two questions:

1. Why does the `height` of the `html,body` still fill up 100% of the viewports height when I specified it should only fill up 40% using `40vh` in the `html,body` declaration?
2. Why is the h1 elements width set to the `70vw` from the `html,body` declaration even though width is not inherited but the height for the h1 isn't set to `40vh` from the `html,body` declaration?

Comment: for 2nd question .. h1 is block element si it takes 100% of container width and height is auto so it depends on the content and not height of parent

Comment: for the 1st question, add border to the declaration of html,body and you will see that it's taking the height/width you specified

Comment: So then the question is why does the background color apply outside of that?

Comment: and that's why i commented, i don't know yet about backround :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif But the width of the element is depending on the width of the parent right? Since whenever I change the `width` on the `html,body` to for example `width:50vh`, `width:60vh`, etc, the red background of the h1 is changed accordingly.

Comment: @ToothyRel yes right ... h1 will take 100% width of parent which mean exactly the same width as the parent (here the body) and we should of course consider margin/padding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually works, but there is a tricky place in css. `html` gets background of `body` if it is unset on `html` itself and viewport is filled by background of html (that's the only inheritance from child in css).

This behavior is specified in [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds):

> The document canvas is the infinite surface over which the document is rendered. [CSS2] Since no element corresponds to the canvas, in order to allow styling of the canvas CSS propagates the background of the root element

> For documents whose root element is an HTML HTML element or an XHTML html element [HTML]: if the computed value of background-image on the root element is none and its background-color is transparent, user agents must instead propagate the computed values of the background properties from that element’s first HTML BODY or XHTML body child element.

I've added background to `html` into your example and you can see, it's fine:

```css
html, body {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

html {
  background: white;
}

h1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
```

The other thing I can do is outline - it'll show where elements actually end:

```css
html, body {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
```

One more interesting case:

```css
html {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

body {
  margin: 40vh 0 0 40vw;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);
}

html, body {
  border: 8px solid;
}
```

Comment: Why downvoting? :(

Comment: *html gets background of body if it is unset on html itself and viewport* where i can read about this ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, updated the answer.

Comment: Is it better to just style the `body` element and not style the `html` element at all?

Comment: @ToothyRel, why? `html` is useful for `rems`, for example.

Comment: I am just confused if the `html` gets the `body` `background-color` or vice versa? `It is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element.` That's what it said in the link I am not sure why.

Comment: @ToothyRel, me neither.

Comment: @Qwertiy One last question. In the code snippet where you draw the outline why is there space on the top between the red background and the top of the yellow. I added `margin:0` and it removed the left space but not the top space.

Comment: @ToothyRel, it's margin collapse and margin from `h1` tag. You can remove that margin or add `border` to the `body` to prevent collapsing.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you are seeing entire background as yellow is because

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas [...]

Try giving a different color to body and you will see the difference

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 70vw;
      height: 40vh;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    h1 {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:blue;">
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

[Read here in details](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background)

Comment: even if you remove background from HTML we see it too, you can keep only the one in the body

Comment: @TemaniAfif, nope.

Comment: remove the one of html also :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif and that is because the HTML takes the background-color of BODY and since the canvas takes from HTML

Comment: yes that's what i meant too ;) as it's not only about background of HTML, but also the trick about the background of body going to the HTML

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds

Comment: `The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas` What exactly is the `root element` and the `canvas` in this case? Is the root element the `body` or the `html`? And is the canvas simply the browser window (like there is no element that corresponds to it)?