# Background images on hover

Tags: html, css

How can I create a background image on hover that is centered and sits behind the text paragraph but ontop of the gradient animation?

https://codepen.io/glittergirl/pen/mjopmW

```
img{
display: none;
max-width: 50%;
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
justify-content: center;
}

span:hover + img{
display: block;
}

.photo img{
max-width: 30%;
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50); 
}
```

Oh and lastly if anyone knows why my rotated text isn't being effected by my styling?? driving me crazy

Comment: it's good to ask one question at a time ...

Comment: duplicate of the first one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237586/linear-gradient-is-repeating-itself-on-body-tag/48237995#48237995 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858633/background-image-not-centering-keeps-repeating/48862362#48862362

Comment: duplicate of the last question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css in your code, it will work

```
p { position:relative; z-index:1;}

img{ position: fixed; z-index: 0; opacity: 1; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); top: 50%; }
```