# background color which is 50% of the height of the window CSS

Tags: html, css

Trying to achieve a background on a page that is "split in two"; two colors on opposite sides, do this with linear-gradient but if some element(div) large height background color repeat

```
<body>
 <div class="blocktest">
  test
 </div>
</body>
```

css :

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000 50%, #ffffff 0%);
  height:100vh;
}
.blocktest {
  height:1500px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/230190/)

I want 50% of the page color1 and the rest of the page color is color2

Comment: background-repeat: no-repeat; ? If I get you right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `min-height` instead of `height`:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000 50%, #ffffff 0%);
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.blocktest {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocktest">
  test
</div>
```

Actually your `body` is limited to `100vh` and [background is getting propagated to root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998676/why-does-the-height-on-html-element-not-have-effect/47998865#47998865) in order to cover the whole screen. So you see 2 backgrounds, the one of the root element and above it the one of the body.

If you keep `height:100vh` and add another background to `html` you will notice this:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000 50%, #ffffff 0%);
  height: 100vh;
}

.blocktest {
  height: 1500px;
}
html {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocktest">
  test
</div>
```

In case you want to only cover `100vh` of your background, make the `html` background white or disable the repeat:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000 50%, #ffffff 0%);
  height: 100vh;
  /* Or background-repeat:no-repeat */
  margin:0;
}

.blocktest {
  height: 1500px;
}
html {
 background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocktest">
  test
</div>
```

Another related question : [How to remove the stripes that appears when using linear gradient property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502338/how-to-remove-the-stripes-that-appears-when-using-linear-gradient-property/48503609#48503609)